# Simplexml (invalid argument supplied foreach)

Tags: foreach, simplexml, arguments

ERROR= Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [path]/deals2.php on line 168

The XML: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/2sjdd

No idea what i'm doing wrong. Never ran into this issue before.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=mykey&division=houston&format=xml');

foreach($xml->deals->list-item as $shortcut)
{
$title = $shortcut->{'title'};

echo $title;

}
```

Comment: (a) please don't put XML in an _image_ -- that turns an already obtuse format into a useless format (b) please use the [standard stack overflow image hosting](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are no "deals" element name in your xml
2. Every element name that has a dash symbol '-' must be escaped with {'some-element'} so even if list-item element would exist (it does not) you would need to escape it. http://www.kombitz.com/2010/02/10/php-xml-problem-hyphen-in-the-element-name/
3. I modified your code to

   foreach($xml->meta->code as $a) { echo $a; }

And it worked fine. Try my advice above and try using elements that actually exist.

And by the way, your XML is not even properly structured. What is that

```
<response/>
```

doing there?? A lot of errors. :)

Comment: The XML is being pulled from Yipit. Out of my hands :(

But yes, the hyphen was the issue. Have used xpath and {'list-item'}

Thanks!